# Why is Hyper-V reinstallation not working?

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v

I've been trying to get Docker for Windows to work on my PC (Windows 10 Pro). I spent about a day trying different solutions, until I found a [suggestion](https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/1221#issuecomment-337770743) to uninstall Hyper-V and reinstall from an elevated PowerShell prompt.

So, it half-worked. The uninstall worked perfectly. After rebooting, I tried to reinstall. It prompted me to reboot, which I did, and I briefly saw the "Windows is installing updates..." screen, before it changed to "Couldn't install updates", backed out the changes, and left me at the login screen, without Hyper-V. I've tried several times, both with the regular Windows Features UI and elevated PowerShell script, to no avail.

Where do I even start with diagnosing the problem?

Answer (score 0):

So, the answer to my question of where to start diagnosing the problem was: in the Event Viewer, under the System log.

There I found that it couldn't find certain system files. I then remembered that I had been messing with some registry settings to try get Windows to save data on my D drive instead of the C drive. (FWIW, I attempted to change the keys under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows Nt\CurrentVersion\ProfileList`.) I reverted my registry changes, and that was the answer to the Hyper-V question.

Comment: @Biswapriyo Duly edited.